# Add rounded borders to selected corners of an element

Tags: html, css, css-shapes, rounded-corners

How could I go about constructing something like this with pure CSS?

[image: SS]

This is how far I've gotten so far: [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8L4k4uf7/)

I'm struggling with how to get that rounded corner there, even if I continue to add additional `span`s.

---

#### CODE:

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10% auto;
}

.top-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 1px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

h3 {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="top-right"></span>
  <div class="box">
    <h3>Content</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can achieve that by using pseudo elements `::before`/`::after` in `.box` using the properties `border` and `border-radius`

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 3% auto 0 /* changed for demo */
}
h3 {
  color: white;
}
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}
.box::before,
.box::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: solid white;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.box::before {
  top: -15px;
  left: -15px;
  border-radius: 15px 0; /* top-left */
  border-width: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
.box::after {
  bottom: -15px;
  right: -15px;
  border-radius: 0 0 15px; /* bottom-right */
  border-width: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <h3>Content</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Using [pseudo-elements would be the ideal solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37779933/3597276).

This answer is just an alternative. Although not semantically elegant, it's crudely effective.

- Create a container with four divs.
- The first div will be the white border.
- The last div will be your red box.
- The two divs in the middle will be used to conceal areas of the white border.

The HTML is quite simple:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box box1"></div>
    <div class="box box2"></div>
    <div class="box box3"></div>
    <div class="box box4">
        <h3>Content</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

With absolute positioning, `.box2` (green) and `.box3` (blue) can be moved to cover the border.

[image]

The order of the boxes in the source doesn't really matter. But with the HTML above there is no need for the `z-index` property.

Now, the only thing left is to change the background color of boxes 2 and 3 to black.

[image]

Full code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: auto;
}
.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.box1 {
  border: 5px solid white;
  width: 320px;
  height: 170px;
  top: -14px;
  left: -15px;
}
.box2 {
  background-color: black;
  top: -30px;
  left: 30px;
}
.box3 {
  background-color: black;
  top: 30px;
  left: -30px;
}
.box4 {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1"></div>
  <div class="box box2"></div>
  <div class="box box3"></div>
  <div class="box box4">
    <h3>Content</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```