# How to get a border around this polygon?

Tags: html, css

I have created a shape with 5 corners using `polygon` as shown below.

[image]

This is the css needed to make it:

```
div {
    width: 280px;
    height: 280px;
    background: #1e90ff;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%, 0 48%, 0% 0%);
    clip-path: polygon(75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%, 0 48%, 0% 0%);
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
}
```

Unfortunately I cannot get it to add a black border all around the shape (it is missing on the right side). How would I do that?

I have created a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/d8tb4g0z/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add border in my clip-path: polygon(); CSS style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31854185/how-to-add-border-in-my-clip-path-polygon-css-style)

Comment: There is no way to add a border using `clip-path`, but you can simulate the poligon using an square + triangle

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37779742/3597276

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `border` property goes around the outside of an element, and the `clip-path` property applies a mask to an element. So, as far as other CSS rules are concerned, you're still dealing with a rectangle. Because of this, you can't simply apply a border.

It's not impossible to get very close to the effect you want, however. Using (and abusing) CSS pseudo-elements, borders, and filters you can create the same shape plus an outline with only a single HTML div.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 210px;
  height: 280px;
  background: #1e90ff;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  filter:
    drop-shadow( 0px  3px 0 black)
    drop-shadow( 0px -3px 0 black)
    drop-shadow( 3px  0px 0 black)
    drop-shadow(-3px  0px 0 black);
  -webkit-filter:
    drop-shadow( 0px  3px 0 black)
    drop-shadow( 0px -3px 0 black)
    drop-shadow( 3px  0px 0 black)
    drop-shadow(-3px  0px 0 black);
}
div::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  left: 210px;
  top: 0;
  border-left: 70px solid #1e90ff;
  border-right: 70px solid transparent;
  border-top: 140px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 140px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

So, what's going on here?

The main div element is just the rectangular portion of the shape (with rounded top-left and bottom-left corners). It also has an `::after` [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) which creates the triangle shape. The triangle shape is done using the CSS [border-triangle hack](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/).

Okay, so that creates the shape without having to mask off any of the element, but a border still can't be applied directly, since I've already (ab)used the border to create the triangle. Using a CSS [outline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) or [box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) would be the next logical choice, but both properties go all the way around the element's bounding-box... ignoring features like rounded corners or hacky transparent borders.

Enter the CSS filter property. This provides a family of post-processing filters. The important thing to note is that they treat the element as a transparency mask when being applied, rather than respecting the element's bounding-box... and there is a drop-shadow filter!

Unfortunately, it's not quite as flexible as the box-shadow property in that it doesn't have a "spread" parameter which can be used to create solid shapes that are larger than the element. To get around this, we need to cast a drop-shadow in every direction: up, down, right, and left. That's where this monstrosity comes in:

```
filter:
  drop-shadow( 0px  3px 0 black)
  drop-shadow( 0px -3px 0 black)
  drop-shadow( 3px  0px 0 black)
  drop-shadow(-3px  0px 0 black);
```

Ta-da!

Expanding on this: this works on any shape you can manage to create (as long as it done without clipping). Just apply a drop-shadow filter to the element, or to a parent/wrapper div (if it's a multi-element shape) to get a border.

Answer (score 2):

I'm on a bit of a pseudo kick here, but You can always recreate the element with a black color and throw it behind the original, giving the impression of an outline. Suitable for most purposes, the proposal is demonstrated in this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MeJorM

CSS in the codepen has been changed up a bit. Your original is "`.orig`".

```
div.orig {
  position:relative;
    width: 280px;
    height: 280px;
    background: #1e90ff;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%, 0 48%, 0% 0%);
  clip-path: polygon(75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%, 0 48%, 0% 0%);
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  display:block;
}
div.abc {
  position:relative;
    width: 280px;
    height: 280px;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%, 0 48%, 0% 0%);
  clip-path: polygon(75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%, 0 48%, 0% 0%);
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  display:block;
}
div.abc div.def{
  top:-0.02em;
  left:-0.2em;
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
    width: 278px;
    height: 280px;
    background: #1e90ff;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%, 0 48%, 0% 0%);
  clip-path: polygon(75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%, 0 48%, 0% 0%);
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
}
```

Comment: good solution. you could even use an `::after` pseudo-element to render the background one to avoid the need for creating a second div in the markup.

Comment: Yeah, I knew it could be done with pseudos (hence my "pseudo-kick" comment) but I wanted to show the proposal without them for the sake of browser support.